# Using dates in a batch file name

Tags: batch, script, batch-file, shell-script, vbscript

I have a file that is generated with the current date using the Month, Day and Year. Previously this file did not include a date and I used a script with the  _%All% in a batch file to move the file to a different folder and this works fine.

I now need the correct syntax to use so that the script will take the file with the current date and continue to have the script move the file into a backup folder.

The following is the script that has been used successfully.

```
@echo off
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(
  Set DayW=%%A
  Set Day=%%B
  Set Month=%%C
  Set Year=%%D
  Set All=%%A%%B%%C%%D
  )

move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1.CSV \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\OCR1.CSV
ren \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\OCR1.CSV OCR1_%All%.CSV
move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1.CSV.bak \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\OCR1.CSV.bak
ren \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\OCR1.CSV.bak OCR1_%All%.CSV.bak
```

The issue now is that the file generated each day will also include the date as in the following: OCR1081916.CSV.

What is the correct way to use the date variable so that it will move the OCR1 file regardless of the date?

Comment: We are neither mind readers or psychic. Please [edit] your question and include all the relevant information. That includes some example file names you want to move and, of course, the **missing batch file** that doesn't work.

Comment: You were asked to [edit] the question. This is so your code can be properly formatted and readable (which is not the case if the code is in a comment).

Comment: What is the output of `date /t` in your locale?

Comment: The output is Eastern Time.  This is an example from August 15. OCR1_Mon08152016.CSV

Comment: So instead of `OCR1_Mon08152016.CSV` you want the name to be `OCR1081516.CSV`? In other words `%All%` should be `081516`? Please be clear and give examples of the source and target filenames (which is what I asked for in my very first comment).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. At this point since the file is generated with a date each day all I need is for the script to move the file from the original location to the backup location.  I tried a new script below but this doesn't appear to work.                                                                   @echo off

move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1*.CSV \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\OCR1*.CSV

move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1*.CSV.bak \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\OCR1*.CSV.bak

Comment: You don't need the filename on the move target, just the directory.

Comment: ``move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1*.CSV \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\``

Comment: ``move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1*.CSV.bak \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\``

Answer (score 0):

#### I need the script to move the file from the original location to the backup location

> At this point since the file is generated with a date each day

You can scrap most of your batch file in this case. All the code to manipulate the date and to rename files is not needed.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1*.CSV \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\
move \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR1_CRM\OCR1*.CSV.bak \\crserverXX\Batch\ASCII\OCR_Backup\
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [move](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) - Move a file from one folder to another.